# Why are affine functions called "affine" functions?

Tags: terminology, mathematical-writing

I am learning about affine functions and I do not understand why a certain type of function (functions that are in the form of $f(x)=ax+b$) are called affine functions. I read about the word "affine" and I know that it means related, but I do not understand how is it related to this type of function and what was the reason behind this naming. I believe that understanding the reason behind namings can help one better understand a concept.

Comment: Did you try to google it?

Comment: From the OED, under "affine"
 B. adj.
 
1. Closely connected or linked. Freq. with to,...

2. Math. Of a transformation: that preserves collinearity, relationships of parallelism, and ratios of distance; (of geometry) dealing with properties unchanged by such a transformation; relating to or involving such transformations.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Jeff Miller](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html), the adjective *affinis* (in Latin: "bordering", "adjacent", "linked by marriage") was introduced in geometry by Euler, in analogy to *similis*, to denote a weaker equivalence relation  than the latter: "Because curves originated this way do keep a certain Affinity between them, we will name these curves  *affine*".

> AFFINE. Affinis and affinitas were first used by Leonhard Euler in
>   *Introductio in analysin infinitorum* (1748) Chapter XVIII: *De
>   similitudine et affinitate linearum curvarum*. He also wrote (II.
>   xviii. 239): "Quia Curvae hoc modo ortae inter se quandam Affinitatem
>   tenent, has Curvas affines vocabimus."

Comment: from what book is this explanation ?

Comment: It's from the linked on-line text, by Jeff Miller

Comment: that website is amazing. thank you.